# How can I set data to field with CKEditor in Protractor test?

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor, protractor

My issue is that I got message, "element not visible" in protractor when I tried to set data into field with CKEditor. 
Application is working with AngularJS.

```
element(by.model("question.translations[lang.locale].answer")).sendKeys("Test answer e2e!!!");
```

How can I set (or get) data to field with CKEditor in Protractor test?
HTML code:

```html
<div ng-repeat="lang in languages">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-icon right">
       <div ckeditor="CKoptions" ng-model="question.translations[lang.locale].answer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I try this

```js
var value = 'Hello';
browser.executeScript(function (arguments) {
    window.CKEDITOR.instances.html_editor.setData(arguments[0]); 
}, value);
```

I get the error: Failed: unknown error: Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution

```js
browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.css('#cke_editor1 iframe')).click().sendKeys("Test answer e2e"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement protractor.ExpectedConditions to check the visibility of element and send the data to it. If you still face the same issue, please paste the element HTML code. So that i can help.

**Code Snippet**

```
var EC=protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var  
  inputField=element(by.css('div[ckeditor="CKoptions"]'));

  inputField.click();


browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(inputField),8000,'Input filed is not visible');
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(inputField),8000,'Input filed is not  
            clickable');
inputField.sendKeys("Test answer e2e!!!");
```

Comment: When I tried the above code I've got the error: 
more than one element found for locator by.model("question.translations[lang.locale].question") - the first result will be used
Failed: Input filed is not visible
Wait timed out after 8066ms

Comment: @Shol, just update the locator value in above code. or paste HTML i can tell you the locator for that input file element.

Comment: I've added html code in question. How can I update the locator?

Comment: with new locator I still get the error: Failed: Input filed is not visible Wait timed out after 8048ms

Comment: Did you see warning 'more than one element found for...' this time?

Comment: i have introduced inputField.click() operation before send data to it. I think it should work now. Can u check it now

Comment: I just use element.all(by.css('div[ckeditor="CKoptions"]')).first();

Comment: R you sure, input field is first element with by.css('div[ckeditor="CKoptions"]') locator. If not we can get the above error. You need identify, whether input field is first, last or 2, 3.

Comment: I'm sure, input field is not the first element with above locator

Comment: But there are only two elements with ckeditor on the page. For each language in ng-repeat.

Comment: have you tried with second element? element.all(by.css('div[ckeditor="CKoptions"]')).last();

Answer (score 0):

I got it to working by reading the instance by the name in the title field.

```
    var statamentDes = 'Hello';
    browser.executeScript(function (arguments) {
        var name = "editor1" // split title to get this
        window.CKEDITOR.instances[name].setData(arguments); 
    }, statamentDes);
```

```html
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, editor1" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```